# Why can we pass a list for the shape of a NumPy array? Doesn't the shape have to be an int or a tuple of ints?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was reading the official NumPy Documentation for the array creation function [np.empty()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html). The page states that `empty()` takes a shape parameter, allowing the user to specify the shape of the array to be created. The description of the parameter is:

***shape**: int or tuple of int.

Shape of the empty array, e.g., (2, 3) or 2.*

`shape` is explicitly stated to be an **int** or a **tuple of int(s)**. Yet, at the bottom of the page is this example, where `shape` seems to be a **list** of ints:

```py
>>> np.empty([2, 2])  # [2, 2] uses square brackets, so this is a list!
array([[ -9.74499359e+001,   6.69583040e-309],  # array shape matches the list
       [  2.13182611e-314,   3.06959433e-309]]) # values are uninitialized
```

Running the example on my machine gave the same results; NumPy seems to allow using a list to specify the shape of an array. So, my questions are

- **Is this intended behavior** (allowing a list to be used as the shape of a NumPy array)?
- **Is something else going on?** For instance, is the list just being converted to a tuple?

Comment: Often a list of ints is interchangeable with a tuple of ints.  That's the case here.  However, `numpy` has a some cases there the distinction between the two is important; most notably in indexing and creating structured arrays.

Comment: "Is this intended behavior (allowing a list to be used as the shape of a NumPy array)?" Yes; the conversion is trivial, so there is no reason to disallow it. "Is something else going on? For instance, is the list just being converted to a tuple?" Yes, the list is converted to tuple when the array is created. You could easily check this yourself, since it is just the `.shape` attribute of the resulting array.

Comment: `shape` is always returned as a tuple, so must also be stored as such.  What's more important about tuples is the notation is different from lists.  For example `(3,)` cf to `[3]`.  What you quote ` e.g., (2, 3) or 2.` isn't as explicit about being a tuple as you read it.  `e.g.` means 'for example'.  In effect it can be anything that can be made into a tuple, even an array.

Comment: "*there is no reason to disallow it*" it was not supported initially (fortunately, long ago). The core of Numpy is implemented in C. Thus, no, the conversion is not so trivial in C (`PyList_xxx` and `PyTuple_xxx` are two sets of different functions) though it is for Python users. That being said, I agree it makes sense to allow lists.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, tuples was the **only** type supported initially for Numpy shapes, but lists was more recently supported due to [this related bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4009). Thus, Numpy developers are aware of this and **explicitly choose** to support any type of **integer-like sequence**. In fact, comments in the [Numpy code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41d37b714caa1eef72f984d529f1d40ed48ce535/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L245) explicitly states:

> it can be an arbitrary sequence of integer like objects, neither of which is safe

Thus, lists are supported in the code but it is undocumented yet (the documentation is not up to date). Fun fact: `range(2, 6)` is a completely valid shape regarding the Numpy code.

Internally, all shapes descriptors are tuples (see [the code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41d37b714caa1eef72f984d529f1d40ed48ce535/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L385)). Thus, yes, lists and more generally integer-like sequences (including the special case of a scalar integer) are **converted to a tuple**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples and list interchangeably in NumPy in most cases, as such that:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(a) # [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

b = np.array((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
print(b) # [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

print(np.array_equal(a, b))  # True
```

Comment: This does *not* answer the question of the OP: "*Is this intended behavior*?" and "*Is something else going on?*".

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes it is intended behavior (or at least common Python behavior), and no, we don't know (may be you do know) exactly what's going on under the compiled code covers, and it doesn't matter!.  It's quite likely that a scalar input is converted to a tuple before use.